# Can you use a pringles can spectrometer for identifying chemicals

Tags: spectroscopy

There's a lot of designs over the years that I've seen for making simple spectrometers, but I've never seen them tested much beyond pointing them at the different light bulbs in the lab... [Here is an incredibly simple design on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJcl392f8ew) it's just a can, with a slit on one end, and 1/4'th of a cd with the opaque foil part peeled off taped to the other end. If someone gave you that and two beakers, one with salt water, one with distilled water, could you measure the difference spectroscopically - or is that scope design to limited? Do you know of a more powerful scope of the same order of simplicity?

Comment: The CD acts as a grating, however very crude, so not sure how accurate it might be as a *quantitative* instrument. I do know from experience you can pick off elements qualitatively from emissions spectra. Chloride salts dissolved in methanol will give you that. For solutions you need a broadband light source and what you'll get, if anything are absorption spectra - so absence of particular spectral lines. Probably not practical using a CD grating.

Comment: I think I remember a design I came across years ago using a grating they bought for a few bucks online - still simple yet probably a lot more resoultion docscience? ty

Comment: where do you get "broadband light?"

Comment: 'white' light , broad at least in the visible band. If you are working IR, a heating coil or strip.

Comment: You *can* buy gratings on line. Even the very cheep ones will be better than any format of optical disk. For a broadband light source the easy thing is to get a purely incandescent (no phosphors) bulb—perhaps a halogen lamp—though it might help to use a diffuser if you find yourself seeing too much structure from the lamp. Caroline, for instance, sell gratings at US$12 per dozen.

Comment: All that said, the device in the video uses a transmission geometry which is both easy and consistent with the way diffraction is usually introduced. But reflection geometry devices are preferable in a number of ways if you intend to do anything quantitative, and they are not significantly harder to build.